# Java Comparator reversed() method has weird results

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, knapsack-problem

I have a programming assignment regarding the Fractional Knapsack Problem. As is the solution for the problem, we need the items to be filled in the descending order of their profit/weight ratio. I used a custom Comparator for sorting the items.

Check the `profitByWeightComparator` in the Item class below:

```
class Item {
  private int itemNumber;
  private int profit;
  private int weight;

  public Item() {
    profit=weight=0;
  }
  public Item(int itemNumber, int profit, int weight) {
    this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    this.profit = profit;
    this.weight = weight;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "("+this.getItemNumber()+", "+this.getProfit()+", "+this.getWeight()+")";
  }
  public static Comparator<Item> profitByWeightComparator = new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item item1, Item item2) {
      double item1Ratio = (double)(item1.getProfit()/item1.getWeight());
      double item2Ratio = (double)(item2.getProfit()/item2.getWeight());
      return new Double(item1Ratio).compareTo(new Double(item2Ratio));
    }
  };
  public int getItemNumber() {
    return this.itemNumber;
  }
  public int getProfit() {
    return this.profit;
  }
  public int getWeight() {
    return this.weight;
  }
}
```

I used the `reversed()` method of the Comparator class to sort in descending order.

Check the `fillGreedyByProfitPerWeight()` method in the KnapSack class below:

```
class KnapSack {
  Item [] items;
  int capacity;
  KnapSack() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of items: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    items = new Item[n];
    System.out.println("Enter the capacity of the KnapSack: ");
    this.capacity = sc.nextInt();

    int profit = 0;
    int weight = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      System.out.println("Enter Item "+(i+1)+" (Format - Profit<Space>Weight):");
      profit = sc.nextInt();
      weight = sc.nextInt();
      items[i] = new Item((i+1), profit, weight);
    }
    fillGreedyByProfitPerWeight();
  }
  public void fillGreedyByProfitPerWeight() {
    Arrays.sort(items,Item.profitByWeightComparator.reversed());
    fillKnapSack("Greedy by Profit Per Weight");
  }
  public void fillKnapSack(String strategy) {
    double totalProfit = 0d;
    int currItemProfit = 0, currItemWeight = 0, i=0, tempCapacity = capacity;
    ArrayList<Integer> filledItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));
    for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      currItemProfit = items[i].getProfit();
      currItemWeight = items[i].getWeight();
      if(currItemWeight <= tempCapacity) {
        filledItems.add(items[i].getItemNumber());
        totalProfit += currItemProfit;
        tempCapacity -= currItemWeight;
      }
      else {
        break;
      }
    }
    double fraction = (double)tempCapacity/currItemWeight;
    totalProfit += (double)(currItemProfit*fraction);
    System.out.println("KnapSack filled using strategy: "+strategy+".\nMaximum Profit: "+totalProfit);
    System.out.print("Items added: ");
    for(int k:filledItems) {
      System.out.print(k+" ");
    }
    if(fraction != 0d)
      System.out.print("and "+tempCapacity+"/"+currItemWeight+" of "+items[i].getItemNumber());
    System.out.println("\n");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    KnapSack obj = new KnapSack();
  }
}
```

However, it leads to weird results in some cases. For e.g. When I try the following inputs:

```
No. of Items: 5
Capacity: 20
Item 1 (Format - Profit<space>Weight): 20 1
Item 2 (Format - Profit<space>Weight): 10 1
Item 3 (Format - Profit<space>Weight): 10 2
Item 4 (Format - Profit<space>Weight): 40 8
Item 5 (Format - Profit<space>Weight): 60 11
```

Expected output for Maximum Profit is 125 (Item 1, Item 2, Item 5, Item 3 and 5/8th of Item 4), but the obtained output is as follows:
(Please check the link as I am not allowed to embed images yet)

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtOk3.png)

Note that the sort order is messed up, as Item 5 should not be last in the reversed sorted order, it must be 3rd. What might be the culprit here?

Comment: Just for the record: you dont need to create new Double objects. `Double` has a **static** `compareTo(double, double)` method already!

Comment: Have you written unit tests for your `Comparator`? Better to do that than to ask questions about it in the context of broader complex code.

Comment: In your `profitByWeightComparator`, you're doing integer division and then casting the result to `double`. You need to cast *before* dividing.

Comment: @GhostCat I checked the method, and it is actually `Double.compare()`

Comment: The duplicate is not very good one, because it asks for division directly, while this question wants to do the comparison, which can be done without division. Voting to re-open.

Comment: @SaketKulkarni Then have my upvote for being more diligent than me. I was too lazy to lookup the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparator performs division incorrectly: rather than converting `int` to `double` and then dividing, it divides first, and then converts the result to `double`. The fraction is gone by then, so the results do not sort correctly.

Change the comparator as follows:

```
public static Comparator<Item> profitByWeightComparator = new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item item1, Item item2) {
        double item1Ratio = ((double)item1.getProfit())/item1.getWeight();
        double item2Ratio = ((double)(item2.getProfit())/item2.getWeight();
        return Double.compare(item1Ratio, item2Ratio);
    }
};
```

Now the division is done in `double`s, and comparison is done without truncating the fractional part.

If weights are strictly positive, and `profit * weight` does not overflow an `int`, you can skip division altogether, comparing ratios like this:

```
public static Comparator<Item> profitByWeightComparator = new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item item1, Item item2) {
        return Integer.compare(
            item1.getProfit() * item2.getWeight()
        ,   item2.getProfit() * item1.getWeight()
        );
    }
};
```

Comment: The comparison without division is actually a great idea. Really impressive.